# Print UTF-32 string with wprintf

Tags: c11

I am migrating some code from using `wchar_t` to `char32_t`, and when compiling with the `-Werror=pointer-sign` flag set, I am getting the following issue:

```c
// main.c

#include <uchar.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    wprintf(U"some data\n");
}
```

Compiling: `gcc -std=c11 -Werror=pointer-sign main.c`

Output:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:10: error: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘wprintf’ differ in signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]
  wprintf(U"some data\n");
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:2:
/usr/include/wchar.h:587:12: note: expected ‘const wchar_t * restrict’ {aka ‘const int * restrict’} but argument is of type ‘unsigned int *’
 extern int wprintf (const wchar_t *__restrict __format, ...)
            ^~~~~~~
```

To remedy this, I can do:

```c
wprintf((const int *)U"some data\n");

//or
printf("%ls\n", U"some data");
```

Although this is quite a pain. Is there a nice and easy way to do this? What is the real difference between `const unsigned int*` vs `const signed int*`, aside from the data type it points to? Is this possibly dangerous, or should I just disable the flag altogether?

Answer (score 0):

`char32_t` is an *unsigned* type.

`wchar_t` is either *signed* or *unsigned*, depending on implementation.  In your case, it is *signed*.

You can't pass a pointer-to-unsigned where a pointer-to-signed is expected. So yes, you need a type-cast, however you should be casting to `const wchar_t *`, since that is what `wprintf()` actually expects (`wchar_t` just happens to be *implemented* as an `int` on your compiler, but don't cast to that directly):

```c
wprintf((const wchar_t *)U"some data\n");
```

It doesn't get much cleaner than that, unless you wrap it in your own function, eg:

```c
int wprintf32(const char32_t *str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);
    int result = vwprintf((const wchar_t *)str, args);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

wprintf32(U"some data\n");
```

Note that this code will not work properly *at all* on platforms where `sizeof(wchar_t) < sizeof(char32_t)`, such as Windows.  On those platforms, where `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2, you will have to actually *convert* your string data from UTF-32 to UTF-16 instead, eg:

```c
int wprintf32(const char32_t *str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int result;

    va_start(args, str);

    if (sizeof(wchar_t) < sizeof(char32_t))
    {
        wchar_t *str = convert_to_utf16(str); // <-- for you to implement
        result = vwprintf(str, args);
        free(str);
    }
    else
        result = vwprintf((const wchar_t *)str, args);

    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

wprintf32(U"some data\n");
```